# Unable to POST Multipart Form in Robot Framework Using Request Library

Tags: automation, request, robotframework, multipartform-data

I have the following request in postman:
[image]

I have been using request library since the beginning automation on API: https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-requests/doc/RequestsLibrary.html#POST%20On%20Session

I tried to automate based on the postman request above with several trial and errors:
[image]

It always return 400 although the headers value set already correct:
[image]

[image]
What did I miss in the steps above?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a false-negative due to the framework used by developers.
The developer has updated their framework and it works fine now.
No issues on the Robot Framework Request Library

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass file descriptor not dictionary and "POST On Session" accepts file as "data" argument not "files". Try this

```
${file_stream} =    Get File For Streaming Upload    ${file_path}
${response} =    POST On Session    ${alias}    ${URI}    data=${file_stream}
```

On the second line you should add the rest arguments.

P.S. Next time please don't post code as screenshot, it makes hard for someone to copy and run it.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. Already tried the suggested solutions but still does not work.

Comment: Can you update the question with updated test case and logs?

Comment: Hi, it returned the following:
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Invalid request payload JSON format"}

Comment: If you get 4xx error it means there is an error in request itself. So in this case server is expecting JSON payload but you are sending file. Make sure if URL route accepts file.